# Is there anyway to break the cubic harmonics in condensed matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, group-theory, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

Since I started doing the calculation of condensed matters, the two $e_g $ orbitals or  three $t_{2g }$ orbitals are assumed equivalent and I have never doubted this. From most books, this is also assumed as a trivial conclusion.
I was wondering if there's a way to make them non-degenerate?

Comment: Please consider spelling out acronyms and defining terms, this makes it more accessible to a wider audience and makes the question more self contained.

Comment: eg? t2g? r2d2 too?

Comment: @triatticus you're not wrong but this comment applies to most questions about any advanced topic here.

Comment: @Triatticus I agree that giving some context would be useful, but $e_{g}$ and $t_{2g}$ are just conventional symmetry labels that aren't easily spelled out. A while back I wrote [another answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4691/671) dissecting the meaning of these labels, but I think for most practitioners they're just arbitrary names assigned to some states for some obscure reason.

Comment: Even if the targeted subset of physicists understand it (I've never personally seen those symmetry labels for example), it's still makes the question more clear and also raises the searchability of the question by expanding on variables with their names and such. These questions should help further askers down the line

Comment: Sorry for that. It's my first time asking question on stackexchange. I tried to add tags about condensed matter physics and espeficially for $d$-electrons or strongly correlated systems. But I didn't find that.
Thanks for all the reminding.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the symmetry of the system. If there is spherical symmetry, the five (10 with spin) $d$-orbitals are degenerate. In a cubic crystal field this splits into $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$ orbitals. If you lower the symmetry further you can split the degeneracy within either/both of the $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$ manifolds. For example, tetragonal symmetry occurs in many transition metal oxides, resulting in the following structure:

[image]

The figure is from the book "Physics of Transition Metal Oxides" by Maekawa et al. (Springer), which you may find useful if you're interested in such systems. Also see the [Jahn-Teller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect). Alternatively, textbooks on inorganic chemistry can be quite informative on these topics. Finally, I will also mention that a rather different scenario occurs in heavy transition metal oxides such as the iridates, where strong spin-orbit coupling splits the $t_{2g}$ manifold.

Comment: A very good answer! Thanks! This question is actually from an automatically symmetrise operation of DMFT calculation which forces the 2 $e_g$ orbitals and 3 $t_{2g}$ equivalent.